# Add CSS class to imageLinkWrap

Tags: typo3

I can't add a CSS class to an image over

```
imageLinkWrap.linkParams.ATagParams.dataWrap =  class="popup-image"
```

when I change:  `if ($content == $string) {}` to `if ($content) {}` in TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer `function imageLinkWrap` the class will be added.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Did you find an solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it without a dataWrap?

```
imageLinkWrap.linkParams.ATagParams =  class="popup-image"
```

Since you are using a static text and not a variable, you do not need a "wrap". You can simply use it so, as linkParams used as a [typolink](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html).